# Feed URL from HTML using Python

Tags: python, html-parsing, urllib2

The RSS feed URL is available a site's meta data (if one available). Is there a way to extract the feed URL(S) of a page using `urllib2` or `HTMLParser` modules? Or is there a better module available?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer [lxml](http://lxml.de/). It has a very nice API, and it's XPath support makes this fairly simple to accomplish:

```
import lxml.html
doc = lxml.html.parse(url_to_site)
feeds = doc.xpath('//link[@type="application/rss+xml"]/@href') # list feed urls
```